# Convert from hex string to decimal the numbers of a pem file

Tags: openssl, hex, decimal, rsa, primes

I am using the following command to view the contents of a private key file:

```
openssl rsa -in mykey.key -text -inform PEM -noout
```

I see various sections such as:

```
modulus:
    00:b9:cd:e6:d2:d5:e8:f1:44:2f:17:c0:89:8b:d0:
    b2:ef:9f:34:5b:17:ca:bc:51:d8:67:71:74:e9:48:
    75:f6:cf:5c:e7:54:7f:c7:2e:0a:54:c3:74:b5:7f:
```

How is this number converted to decimal? Is it from left to write appending the corresponding hex byte or some other way?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37075/how-can-i-obtain-the-raw-decimal-value-of-an-rsa-keys-modulus

Comment: It isn't converted to decimal. It is converted to binary by treating those as hex digits from most to least significant.

Comment: @user207421: So from left to right, each is a byte and the most significant byte is the one that starts that hex string? I.e in this example `00`? The separation with `:` is it for readability?